# NSImage transparency

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

I'm trying to set a custom drag icon for use in an NSTableView. Everything seems to work but I've run into a problem due to my inexperience with Quartz.

```
- (NSImage *)dragImageForRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)dragRows tableColumns:(NSArray *)tableColumns event:(NSEvent *)dragEvent offset:(NSPointPointer)dragImageOffset
{
 NSImage *dragImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
 NSString *count = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [dragRows count]];

 [dragImage lockFocus]; 
 [dragImage compositeToPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:0.5];
 [count drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint withAttributes:nil];

 [dragImage unlockFocus];
 return dragImage;
}
```

Essentially what I'm looking to do is render my icon.png file with 50% opacity along with an NSString which shows the number of rows currently being dragged. The issue I'm seeing is that my NSString renders with a low opacity, but not my icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you’re drawing your icon on top of itself. What you probably want is something like this:

```
- (NSImage *)dragImageForRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)dragRows tableColumns:(NSArray *)tableColumns event:(NSEvent *)dragEvent offset:(NSPointPointer)dragImageOffset
{
 NSImage *icon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
 NSString *count = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [dragRows count]];

 NSImage *dragImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[icon size]] autorelease];

 [dragImage lockFocus]; 
 [icon drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:0.5];
 [count drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint withAttributes:nil];

 [dragImage unlockFocus];
 return dragImage;
}
```

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks you.

Comment: Also, [`compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:` is deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:). Use `drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:` instead.

Comment: Good catch; I’d blanked that out.