# NSImage + Transparency?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, transparency, opacity, nsimage

I'm not sure whether it's the right thing to ask for... but what I want is basically **"whitewashing" an NSImage, or reducing its opacity**... (sort of an "inactive" icon in Finder? something like that)

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

*I've tried the example shown here ([NSImage transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866532/nsimage-transparency)), but it definitely did NOT work for me...*

(Btw, the NSImage will be in an `ImageAndTextCell`, if that makes any difference...)

Comment: Have you tried compositing with an alpha?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need to do is draw the image with an alpha of less than `1.0`. In your implementation of `ImageAndTextCell`, just use something like this in the `-drawWithFrame:inView:` method:

```
[image drawInRect:someRect 
         fromRect:NSZeroRect 
        operation:NSCompositeSourceOver //this draws the image using the alpha mask
         fraction:0.5];
```

Comment: Good. NSCompositingOperationSourceOver is now used instead of the deprecated NSCompositeSourceOver.